# Build PDFium in Android

Tags: android, pdf, android-ndk, android-build, pdfium

I am facing a problem. I have to add a PDF reader support to my Android App (now I'm using Mupdf but I need to change it).

I found PDFium project (https://code.google.com/p/pdfium/) and I think it is what I need for my needs.
I haven't too much experience in Android and I've not been able to build it for Android, I've followed the build instructions from here https://code.google.com/p/pdfium/wiki/Build with no good results.

Could you give some hint or advice to achieve build this tool in Android?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: What specifically happened? Compilation errors? Link errors? We can diagnose error messages, but can't do anything with "it didn't work".

Comment: I've followed build instructions and I've generated a Visual Studio  project. But now I don't know how to continue... Do I need to build now with Android NDK? I'm quite lost in this momment...

Comment: Whose build instructions? Some quick searching didn't turn up any guides on building pdfium for Android. Yes, you'll need to build with the NDK.

Comment: I'm searching for Android build instructions too... I'm totally ignorant about NDK and C compilation for android, so a quite detailed guide could help...

Comment: @peskarolo Have you successfully build pdfium , Where i can find step to build it.

Answer (score 4):

### How to build?

I recommend building on Linux (virtual machine will suffice),
because Windows is officially not supported and there are many problems on newer versions of OS X.

You will need about 60 GB of free space.

- install OpenJDK 8
- `$ mkdir ~/android_src && cd ~/android_src` or select any other path
- `$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-7.1.1_r28`

  (detailed description available [here](https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html))
- `$ repo sync` and wait...
- clone this repo (or download zip with its content)
- replace makefiles in `~/android_src` with corresponding makefiles from this repo
- `$ cd ~/android_src`
- `$ source build/envsetup.sh`
- `$ cd external/pdfium/fpdfsdk`
- `$ lunch` and select architecture
- `$ mma` and wait ~5 minutes
- library is available in `~/android_src/out/target/product/generic*/obj/lib/libmod*.so`, copy it somewhere
- `$ rm -r ~/android_src/out` before next build

It worked for me, but if doesn't work for you, try installing additional packages listed [here](https://github.com/barteksc/modpdfium/issues/1#issuecomment-259838427).

[Source](https://github.com/barteksc/modpdfium)

Answer (score 3):

Build it within the AOSP
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/pdfium/
Use **mm** or **mma** instructions to build only the pdfium module

I've only successfully built the shared library but haven't take it into practice.

Comment: sorry for asking, but what do you mean for mm or mma instructions? can you expand this?

Comment: They're all shell functions, so be sure to initialized the environment by `. build/envsetup.sh` or `source build/envsetup.sh`.